# Driving motors with image processing on raspberry pi

Tags: image, python-2.7, python-multiprocessing, raspberry-pi3, motordriver

I have a question about processing the image while driving a motor. I did some researches, probably I need to use multiprocessing. However, I couldn't find out how to run two processors together.

Let's say I have two functions as imageProcessing() and DrivingMotor(). With coming information from imageProcessing(), I need to update my DrivingMotor() function simultaneously. How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In multiprocessing, you must create two process(process means program in execution) and must implement  interproccesing communication  methods to communicate process each other, this is tedious,hard and inefficient way .Multiproccesing less efficient than multithreading.Therefore I think you should multithread ,it is very efficient way ,communication  between thread is very  easy, you can use global data for communication.

You shall create  two threads, one thread is handle imageProcessing() ,and other thread DrivingMotor().Operating system  handled execution of thread,Operating system run  synchronous these threads.

there is basic tutorial for multithreading below links

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm